# How can I get the maximum length of datetime.strftime?

Tags: python, datetime

Currently I'm working on a command line program and there I print out dates.

I do this with `datetime.datetime.strftime`:

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime(2012,12,12)
date_str = d.strftime(config.output_str)
```

Where `config.output_str` is a format string that can be set by the user.

Is there a way to tell how long the string `date_str` will be at maximum?

Especially if a format string like `u'%d %B %Y'` is used, where the length of the month (`%B`) depends on the language of the user?

Comment: Are you setting the locale at all with the `locale` module?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No I don't. At least for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not setting the locale with the `locale` module, then Python uses the C locale and you can predict the maximum length produced. All strings will be in English and the maximum length per format character is known.

Parse the string yourself, count the non-format characters and map format characters to the maximum length for that field.

If you *were* to use `locale`, you'll need to calculate the max length per language. You can automate the locale-dependent fields by looping over the months, weekdays, and AM/PM and measuring the max length for the `%a`, `%A`, `%b`, `%B`, `%c`, `%p`, `%x` and `%X` formats. I'd do that on the fly as needed.

The rest of the formats do not vary by locale and have a documented maximum length (the examples in the [`strptime` table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) are typical, you can rely on those documenting the field length).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But is there a more general solution?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens: You mean when you use `locale`? Create a map for each locale as needed.

Comment: "*predict*" is very unconvincing to me. I don't expect that names of moths can change... but technically probably they can. I think question is how to *know*. Same goes for day and year representation. Is it possible for the locale to have 5 character year? I'd expect it is, and there are no fields that report maximum length of fields (except for numeric and monetary I guess).

Comment: @luk32: there are 6 fields that can vary by locale. The year is never going to be 5 digits, no.

Comment: OK, thanks, IMO the only way is also to loop through the variable legth fields for every value and get max length. I think they length of other fields are not defined, but they are fixed, so it's sufficient to render any value only once and check it's length. Could you please point to a place that says for example that year is not going to be 5 digits? (I tried to find it but cannot. Can't find any standard for locales.) Anyways, I think you made a very nice update to the answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah this looks reasonable. I already thought about looping through the 7*12 possibilities, but I hoped there would be some precomputed table or something.

Comment: @luk32: half the world's computers would break if a year is going to be 5 digits. All C `strftime` and `strptime` documentation (which is the basis for Python's implementation) I can find makes the assumption you know this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know but its stupid after Y2K problems to have Y10K problems, IMO. I am not asking for laughs only =).

Comment: @luk32 you have 32Bits timestamps so we have the 2038 problem.

Comment: @luk32: We'll have 2038 problems **long** before we have the year 10000.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens Ok, fair enough. Thank you both for clarifications. Quite helpful.

Comment: @luk32: but most of all the `datetime` type doesn't allow for years beyond 9999; it cannot hold a longer year to format.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens: it is a 7 + 12 test; test the month and week formats separately, once, and the `%c`, `%x` and `%X` formats are bound by the  maximum value for the weekday and month.

Comment: This is not true for every locale. In Hebrew, for example, you have a special month (Hadar B') that comes once every four years. Its name is also longer than the rest. You will therefore get different results for leap and non-leap years. Same goes for Hebrew years. In the Jewish year 6000 the year field length would be 2. Right now it is about 8. A year later it will be 4. 10 years later 6.

Comment: @kichik: That is interesting! So you need to use a leap year to base your length tests of. And there are no longer months in that year?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a leap year that's also not too close to a multiple of a 1000 so you get proper year length. But that's just Hebrew calendar. There are probably others with similar oddities we are simply not aware of. The point is it is hard to make assumptions here.

Comment: @kichik: It is reasonable to make *some* assumptions, until proven otherwise.

Comment: True. I think it is very safe to assume no one will be using a Hebrew locale with a Jewish instead of a Gregorian calendar. As long as you're aware of the risks...

Comment: @kichik: `datetime` only supports the Gregorian calendar, so we are safe there!

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution I wrote to solve this, for those who are interested.

I use the given format string `format_str` to figure out how long it could get.
Therefore I assume that only the month and the day can very in length.
The function loop over the months to see which has the longest form and then I loop over the days with the previously found month.

```
import datetime

def max_date_len(format_str):

    def date_len(date):
        return len(date.strftime(format_str))

    def find_max_index(lst):
        return max(range(len(lst)), key=lst.__getitem__)

    # run through all month and add 1 to the index since we need a month
    # between 1 and 12
    max_month = 1 + find_max_index([date_len(datetime.datetime(2012, month, 12, 12, 12)) for month in range(1, 13)])

    # run throw all days of the week from day 10 to 16 since
    # this covers all weekdays and double digit days
    return max([date_len(datetime.datetime(2012, max_month, day, 12, 12)) for day in range(10, 17)])
```